# "la corbata" vs "la gorbata"

Tags: vocabulario

On Memrise.com, there is a course titled *Spanish Nouns for Young Kids*.

Level 1 of the course lists the following word/definition pairs:

- la corbata     (tie)
- la gorbata     (the tie)

Why does one word mean "tie" and the other mean "the tie"? Also, why is that I've visited two different online Spanish dictionaries, and neither has an entry for "gorbata"?

Comment: It's just a mistake. It should be *corbata* (tie) and *la corbata* (the tie), but often times you'll see vocabulary listed with the definite article (*el/la/los/las*, that is, *the*) so that you can identify the gender/number, though it may not always be in the accompanying translation.

Comment: @guifa, I think you should post the above comment as an answer, there's no doubt that you are totally correct.

Comment: @JoseMaria I'd actually rather let someone else — with much less reputation — answer so they can get the reputation and practice writing good answers.

Comment: @guifa: I also encourage you to answer. It's nice to "share the rep," but rep ought to be considered a side-effect here, and not the primary reason to post. What's most important is providing valuable content, and "making the Internet a better place."

Comment: @guifa *A bove maiori discit arare minor*, estoy seguro que la respuesta de un usuario tan experimentado como tú, es el mejor ejemplo para aquellos usuarios con menor experiencia en el sitio ;)

Comment: Gorbata doesn't exists

Comment: [`Gorbata`](https://eu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorbata) is the Basque word for `tie`, could this be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- La corbata = The Tie
- Corbata = Tie

"Gorbata" doesn't exist. It may be just an error in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The tie for me could mean 2 things... A neck tie (**corbata**) or just a regular rope tie (**nudo**). 
Gorbata is not a Spanish word and this website must got it wrong.